# How do I implement the refresh button in the menu bar to refresh the all of the combo box items in their original state?

Tags: python, pyside, qt-designer

Importing libraries.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
from UI import main
```

This is my class which is inheriting and have a constructor

```
class MyQtApp(main.Ui_MainWindow,QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQtApp,self).__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self)
        window size
        self.showNormal()         
        self.submit_pb.clicked.connect(self.fill_box)
        self.Menu()
```

This fill_box is for the combo box, and I have three combo boxes 
model_cb, size_cb and color_cb
And the zeroth index is just an empty string for all of them

```
    def fill_box(self):
        model = self.model_cb.currentText()
        color = self.model_cb.currentText()
        size = self.size_cb.currentText()
        none = ""
        check = True
        if model is none:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self,"Name Required","Please enter the Name!")
            check = False
            return
        if color is none:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self,"Color Required","Please enter the Color!")
            check = False
            return
        if size is none:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self,"Size Required","Please Enter the Size!") 
            check = False
            return
        if check:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Done","Submitted")
```

This Menu function is for the menu bar options what happens if someone click close. I have only two options here 1)close which works fine and 2) Refresh which does not work.

```
    def Menu(self):
        self.actionClose.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.actionRefresh.triggered.connect(self.fill_box1)

    def fill_box1(self):
        #If I do this It will reset all the boxes to its original empty 
        #strings but then I would not have all the methods in the class 
        #to add the functionality.

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()    
    qt_app = MyQtApp()
    qt_app.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I have a combo box with 4 items in it. What I want is whenever user hits refresh combo box goes to index 0 which I think is doable but to Re-display the window with all the methods is what I am not getting it

Comment: Could you include the definition of `main.Ui_MainWindow` as well?

Comment: If it's a matter of resetting the indices of combo boxes to 0 you can do `self.model_cb.setCurrentIndex(0)` etc.